# How to show "next", "previous" buttons on an image (on mouseover)?

Tags: css

I spent many hours trying to show `previous`, `next` and `zoom` buttons on an image (on `mouseover`). This is the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/9TGvq/

**CSS**

```
.imgcon {
  position:relative;
}

.imnav {
  opacity:0.6;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.imgcon:hover .imnav {
  display:inline-block;
}

.prim {
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:33%;
  background:url(/pr.gif)left center no-repeat;
}

.zmim {
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:34%;
  background:url(/zm.gif)center center no-repeat;
}

.neim {
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:33%;
  background:url(/ne.gif)right center no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="imgcon">
        <a href="/maximize"><img src="/image.jpg" width="660" /></a>

        <div class="imnav">
            <a href="/previous">
                <div class="prim"></div>
            </a>
            <a href="/full-size">
                <div class="zmim"></div>
            </a>
            <a href="/next">
                <div class="neim"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works in all browsers except Chrome, so I can not use it. Any ideas how to fix it?

Second problem: I don't want to show all 3 icons on `mouseover`. I want to show them one by one depending of position of the mouse. If mouse rolls over `.prim`, I want to show `.prim`; if mouse rolls over `.zmim`, I want to show `.zmim`, if mouse rolls over `.neim`, I want to show `.neim`.

Comment: Invisible controls seems less than intuitive to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invisible controls seems less than intuitive to me...however

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/9TGvq/4/)

**HTML** /* note added 'control' class */

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="imgcon">
        <a href="/maximize">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg" width="660" />
        </a>

        <div class="imnav">
            <a href="/previous">
                <div class="prim control"></div>
            </a>

            <a href="full-size">
                <div class="zmim control"></div>
            </a>

            <a href="/next">
                <div class="neim control"></div>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgcon{
    position:relative;
    width:660px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.imnav {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin:o auto;
    opacity:0.6;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.imgcon:hover .imnav{display:inline-block;}

.control {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:33%;
    opacity:0;    
}

.control:hover {
    opacity:0.6;
}

.prim{
    background:url('http://i59.tinypic.com/294s94i.gif')left center no-repeat;
}
.zmim{
    width:34%;
    background:url('http://i57.tinypic.com/dgp4xy.gif')center center no-repeat;
}
.neim{
    background:url('http://i62.tinypic.com/2cqfqxf.gif')right center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to make aal icons visible at once, add this code in your css :
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9TGvq/5/)**

```
.imgcon:hover .imnav {display:block}
.imnav {top:5%;}
```